# Create a lorenz curve

Tags: diagrams

For my first real document, I have to create [lorenz curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve). Problem is, I'm pretty new to TeX and I have absolutely no clue about how I should go about this. A google search only reveals this has not been attempted by anyone else, so any help or pointers are welcome.

Comment: What do you have to plot the curves ? Equations ? Sets of values ?
What you will need is the package pgfplot and you can use the axis environment.

Comment: As indicated LMT-PhD, determine your equations, sets of values, then look at this question and answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164991/31034

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have to create that curve from `TeX` or is it just the inclusion of such a curve from another program into a `.tex` file?

Comment: @christian Hupfer, externally is totally fine, but I take that it is possible with only tex, so I will attempt that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do that with  `pstricks`:  the  `pst-func` package has a special command for that. From the doc:

[image]

Comment: It took a while to understand what I was seeing, but this works very well.