# pgfplots complains path is empty

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm trying to fill an area under a curve drew with pgfplots. I've tried the solution outlined [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165666/59902):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!10}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.11,
    standard/.style={%
        clip=false,
        mark=none,
        smooth,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        enlarge x limits=0.15,
        enlarge y limits=0.15,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east}
    }
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand\gaussian{1.0298076 * exp(-(x-2)^2 / 0.48)}
        \pgfplotsset{ticks=none};

        \begin{axis}[standard,every axis plot post/.append style={%
                domain=0:4,samples=200},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$p(x)$},
        enlargelimits=upper]
            \addplot[name path=f,CornflowerBlue]{\gaussian};
            \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0); %%%% The problem
            \addplot[
                thick,
                color=blue,
                fill=blue,
                fill opacity=0.05
            ]
            fill between[
                of=f and axis,
                soft clip={domain=1.6:2.4}
            ];
            \addplot[dashed] coordinates {(2.4,0) (2.4,0.737889)};
            \addplot[dashed] coordinates {(1.6,0) (1.6,0.737889)};
            \node at (axis cs:2.4,0.001) [below] {$\mu + \sigma$};
            \node at (axis cs:1.6,0.001) [below] {$\mu - \sigma$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Intervallo di confidenza}\label{fig:distib_norm}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, in the logs I see

> Package pgf Warning: fill between skipped: the second input path is
>   empty. on input line 55.

The offending line is therefore this one:

```
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);
```

How can it be empty?
This is the result:
[image].

Comment: Well, the path is not empty but to short. Try with `(axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:5,0)`. If you place x axis labels at `(axis cs:1.6,0.001)` and `(axis cs:2.4,0.001)`, it's clear that `axis` path is to short to cut the gaussian path.

Comment: @Ignasi Aw thank you. I read somewhere that the values of `axis cs` had to be between `0` and `1`. Now it works!

Comment: I also remember something similar, so we will have to look for it again ;-)

Comment: Actually `rel axis cs` runs from 0 to 1 where as `axis cs` takes the actual domain dimensions (here from 0 to 4).

Comment: @HarishKumar Ahh that's how it is. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`axis cs` (axis coordinate system) is the coordinate system to be used inside of an axis. It's the default coordinate system, so it's not necessary to prefix coordinates with it.

Therefore, command

```
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);
```

defines a path from coordinate `(0,0)` to coordinate `(1,0)`. This path is too short to intersect with the Gaussian curve which is drawn between `x=0` and `x=4`.

The easiest solution would be to use (remember, no need for `axis cs` prefix)

```
\path[name path=axis] (0,0) -- (5,0);
```

Perhaps you confused `axis cs` with `rel axis cs` (relative coordinate system) which uses the complete axis vectors as units, i.e.

```
\path[name path=axis] (rel axis cs:0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,0);
```

defines axis as the horizontal line between the lower and upper points in axis range. This is what you probably wanted to write.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!10}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.11,
    standard/.style={%
        clip=false,
        mark=none,
        smooth,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        enlarge x limits=0.15,
        enlarge y limits=0.15,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east}
    }
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newcommand\gaussian{1.0298076 * exp(-(x-2)^2 / 0.48)}
        \pgfplotsset{ticks=none};

        \begin{axis}[standard,every axis plot post/.append style={%
                domain=0:4,samples=200},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$p(x)$},
        enlargelimits=upper]
            \addplot[name path=f,CornflowerBlue]{\gaussian};
% Next two lines are valid. Select the one you prefer
%            \path[name path=axis] (0,0) -- (5,0);
            \path[name path=axis] (rel axis cs:0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,0); %%%% The problem
            \addplot[
                thick,
                color=blue,
                fill=blue,
                fill opacity=0.05
            ]
            fill between[
                of=f and axis,
                soft clip={domain=1.6:2.4}
            ];
            \addplot[dashed] coordinates {(2.4,0) (2.4,0.737889)};
            \addplot[dashed] coordinates {(1.6,0) (1.6,0.737889)};
            \node at (2.4,0.001) [below] {$\mu + \sigma$};
            \node at (1.6,0.001) [below] {$\mu - \sigma$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Intervallo di confidenza}\label{fig:distib_norm}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot]