# Insert border to area under plot part 2

Tags: pgfplots

This question builds from the question posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285970/insert-border-to-area-under-plot/285976?noredirect=1#comment690889_285976).  How can I get the plot to show up in red in the region between the shaded region like this:

[image]
Here is the original code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,gray!50}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={gray!50!black}}

\newcommand{\datafile}{Noise2.dat}

\begin{filecontents*}{\datafile}
  Freq   Orig   Filt
100.000, -79.374, -119.392
101.801, -79.858, -119.321
103.634, -78.587, -117.497
105.501, -79.077, -117.437
107.401, -78.735, -116.547
109.335, -81.799, -119.065
111.304, -82.298, -119.021
113.309, -82.329, -118.511
115.349, -81.744, -117.389
117.427, -82.113, -117.223
119.542, -83.602, -118.180
121.695, -83.097, -117.147
123.886, -83.461, -116.985
126.117, -82.194, -115.196
128.389, -83.418, -115.902
130.701, -83.187, -115.155
133.055, -83.285, -114.742
135.451, -83.793, -114.742
137.891, -84.710, -115.156
140.374, -85.018, -114.964
142.902, -85.918, -115.369
145.476, -84.668, -113.628
148.096, -83.836, -112.310
150.763, -84.068, -112.061
153.478, -84.302, -111.818
156.242, -84.040, -111.085
159.056, -82.969, -109.548
161.921, -82.205, -108.324
164.837, -83.149, -108.813
167.806, -83.943, -109.158
170.828, -83.769, -108.542
173.904, -84.410, -108.747
177.036, -85.590, -109.498
180.225, -84.582, -108.067
183.470, -87.734, -110.804
186.775, -86.326, -108.989
190.138, -84.893, -107.156
193.563, -86.280, -108.151
197.049, -87.832, -109.319
200.598, -87.776, -108.888
204.210, -87.978, -108.725
207.888, -86.935, -107.325
211.632, -87.181, -107.223
215.443, -88.478, -108.183
219.324, -87.294, -106.672
223.274, -85.716, -104.777
227.295, -85.793, -104.547
231.388, -87.389, -105.848
235.555, -87.906, -106.081
239.798, -87.386, -105.289
244.116, -88.130, -105.772
248.513, -87.121, -104.515
252.988, -87.494, -104.652
257.545, -87.507, -104.441
262.183, -86.936, -103.660
266.905, -86.413, -102.939
271.712, -85.294, -101.635
276.605, -84.552, -100.722
281.587, -83.760, -99.771
286.658, -81.666, -97.533
291.821, -80.942, -96.678
297.076, -81.625, -97.243
302.427, -81.497, -97.011
307.873, -78.332, -93.755
313.418, -78.452, -93.798
319.063, -81.117, -96.400
324.809, -81.431, -96.663
330.659, -80.621, -95.816
336.614, -82.433, -97.603
342.676, -82.169, -97.328
348.848, -79.901, -95.061
355.130, -80.383, -95.556
361.526, -81.490, -96.688
368.037, -82.843, -98.078
374.665, -84.314, -99.597
381.413, -81.159, -96.502
388.282, -83.309, -98.723
395.275, -81.743, -97.238
402.394, -81.915, -97.501
409.641, -82.141, -97.828
417.018, -82.823, -98.621
424.529, -82.646, -98.563
432.174, -83.165, -99.211
439.958, -83.784, -99.967
447.881, -83.598, -99.927
455.947, -84.321, -100.803
464.159, -82.783, -99.426
472.518, -83.921, -100.731
481.028, -85.274, -102.259
489.691, -84.604, -101.770
498.511, -85.588, -102.942
507.489, -84.458, -102.006
516.628, -84.730, -102.477
525.933, -85.516, -103.467
535.405, -83.314, -101.475
545.047, -85.678, -104.054
10000.000, -117.204, -288.714
\end{filecontents*}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164991/pgfplots-how-to-fill-bounded-area-under-a-curve-using-addplot-and-fill?rq=1
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every plot/.append style={very thick}]
\begin{semilogxaxis}[width=14cm,height=10cm,
                    grid = both,
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.7},
                    ymin =  -130,
                    ymax = -70,
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={\emph{Offset Frequency (Hz)}},
                    ylabel={\emph{Noise}},
                    extra y ticks = {-70}]

\addplot+ [smooth,blue,name path=A] table[mark = none, x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {\datafile};
\addplot+[draw=none,name path=B, domain=500:1000, mark=none] {-130};
\addplot+[gray, draw=red, thick, fill opacity=0.4] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=500:1000}];
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Response.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See new edit, I have replaced border for the shaded region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `intersection segments`. Basically I draw a long path that follows the shaded region, I get the intersection with the plot and draw red over it.

I have also replaced the previous command for drawing the border of the shaded region with this new method, so that you don't have that red line at the bottom of the plot.

**Details:**

[image: one]               [image: two]

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,gray!50}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={gray!50!black}}

\newcommand{\datafile}{Noise.dat}

\begin{filecontents*}{\datafile}
  Freq   Orig   Filt
100.000, -79.374, -119.392
101.801, -79.858, -119.321
103.634, -78.587, -117.497
105.501, -79.077, -117.437
107.401, -78.735, -116.547
109.335, -81.799, -119.065
111.304, -82.298, -119.021
113.309, -82.329, -118.511
115.349, -81.744, -117.389
117.427, -82.113, -117.223
119.542, -83.602, -118.180
121.695, -83.097, -117.147
123.886, -83.461, -116.985
126.117, -82.194, -115.196
128.389, -83.418, -115.902
130.701, -83.187, -115.155
133.055, -83.285, -114.742
135.451, -83.793, -114.742
137.891, -84.710, -115.156
140.374, -85.018, -114.964
142.902, -85.918, -115.369
145.476, -84.668, -113.628
148.096, -83.836, -112.310
150.763, -84.068, -112.061
153.478, -84.302, -111.818
156.242, -84.040, -111.085
159.056, -82.969, -109.548
161.921, -82.205, -108.324
164.837, -83.149, -108.813
167.806, -83.943, -109.158
170.828, -83.769, -108.542
173.904, -84.410, -108.747
177.036, -85.590, -109.498
180.225, -84.582, -108.067
183.470, -87.734, -110.804
186.775, -86.326, -108.989
190.138, -84.893, -107.156
193.563, -86.280, -108.151
197.049, -87.832, -109.319
200.598, -87.776, -108.888
204.210, -87.978, -108.725
207.888, -86.935, -107.325
211.632, -87.181, -107.223
215.443, -88.478, -108.183
219.324, -87.294, -106.672
223.274, -85.716, -104.777
227.295, -85.793, -104.547
231.388, -87.389, -105.848
235.555, -87.906, -106.081
239.798, -87.386, -105.289
244.116, -88.130, -105.772
248.513, -87.121, -104.515
252.988, -87.494, -104.652
257.545, -87.507, -104.441
262.183, -86.936, -103.660
266.905, -86.413, -102.939
271.712, -85.294, -101.635
276.605, -84.552, -100.722
281.587, -83.760, -99.771
286.658, -81.666, -97.533
291.821, -80.942, -96.678
297.076, -81.625, -97.243
302.427, -81.497, -97.011
307.873, -78.332, -93.755
313.418, -78.452, -93.798
319.063, -81.117, -96.400
324.809, -81.431, -96.663
330.659, -80.621, -95.816
336.614, -82.433, -97.603
342.676, -82.169, -97.328
348.848, -79.901, -95.061
355.130, -80.383, -95.556
361.526, -81.490, -96.688
368.037, -82.843, -98.078
374.665, -84.314, -99.597
381.413, -81.159, -96.502
388.282, -83.309, -98.723
395.275, -81.743, -97.238
402.394, -81.915, -97.501
409.641, -82.141, -97.828
417.018, -82.823, -98.621
424.529, -82.646, -98.563
432.174, -83.165, -99.211
439.958, -83.784, -99.967
447.881, -83.598, -99.927
455.947, -84.321, -100.803
464.159, -82.783, -99.426
472.518, -83.921, -100.731
481.028, -85.274, -102.259
489.691, -84.604, -101.770
498.511, -85.588, -102.942
507.489, -84.458, -102.006
516.628, -84.730, -102.477
525.933, -85.516, -103.467
535.405, -83.314, -101.475
545.047, -85.678, -104.054
554.863, -84.979, -103.575
564.856, -85.488, -104.307
575.029, -85.218, -104.265
585.385, -86.101, -105.381
595.928, -84.617, -104.133
606.661, -84.431, -104.186
617.586, -85.522, -105.520
628.709, -86.590, -106.834
640.032, -86.826, -107.320
651.559, -87.389, -108.135
663.293, -86.232, -107.233
675.239, -87.076, -108.335
687.400, -87.267, -108.786
699.780, -86.034, -107.815
712.382, -86.262, -108.308
725.212, -86.480, -108.793
738.273, -84.688, -107.270
751.569, -85.615, -108.468
765.105, -86.937, -110.063
778.884, -85.851, -109.251
792.912, -85.930, -109.606
807.192, -86.156, -110.110
821.729, -86.489, -110.722
836.528, -87.787, -112.301
851.594, -87.913, -112.709
866.931, -85.959, -111.038
882.544, -86.837, -112.200
898.439, -86.963, -112.612
914.619, -86.759, -112.694
931.091, -87.360, -113.583
947.860, -86.890, -113.402
964.931, -87.240, -114.041
982.309, -87.019, -114.111
1000.000, -85.349, -112.732
1018.010, -86.757, -114.432
1036.344, -86.677, -114.645
1055.008, -86.228, -114.490
1074.009, -87.104, -115.660
1093.351, -87.293, -116.144
1113.042, -87.722, -116.869
1133.088, -87.269, -116.712
1153.494, -88.248, -117.988
1174.269, -87.315, -117.353
1195.417, -88.085, -118.421
1216.946, -88.050, -118.684
1238.863, -88.966, -119.899
1261.175, -88.435, -119.668
1283.888, -88.282, -119.815
1307.010, -88.859, -120.693
1330.549, -88.324, -120.459
1354.512, -87.446, -119.882
1378.907, -87.432, -120.170
1403.740, -87.666, -120.706
1429.021, -88.099, -121.442
1454.758, -88.533, -122.180
1480.958, -88.338, -122.288
1507.629, -88.343, -122.598
1534.781, -88.103, -122.663
1562.422, -88.478, -123.343
1590.561, -89.310, -124.482
1619.207, -89.579, -125.058
1648.368, -89.152, -124.938
1678.055, -89.278, -125.373
1708.276, -89.724, -126.129
1739.042, -90.204, -126.920
1770.362, -90.563, -127.591
1802.246, -89.939, -127.281
1834.704, -90.099, -127.757
1867.746, -90.580, -128.556
1901.384, -90.793, -129.089
1935.627, -90.604, -129.224
1970.487, -90.073, -129.020
2005.975, -88.273, -127.551
2042.102, -91.418, -131.032
2078.880, -91.760, -131.716
2116.320, -91.445, -131.750
2154.435, -91.854, -132.516
2193.236, -92.113, -133.141
2232.735, -92.505, -133.911
2272.946, -92.729, -134.526
2313.881, -93.382, -135.585
2355.554, -92.567, -135.194
2397.977, -93.718, -136.791
2441.164, -94.062, -137.604
2485.128, -94.297, -138.336
2529.885, -94.376, -138.944
2575.448, -95.170, -140.304
2621.831, -95.128, -140.867
2669.049, -95.364, -141.755
2717.118, -96.018, -143.110
2766.053, -96.379, -144.227
2815.869, -96.767, -145.430
2866.582, -96.727, -146.268
2918.208, -97.296, -147.780
2970.764, -95.765, -147.261
3024.267, -94.212, -146.788
3078.733, -98.685, -152.410
3134.181, -99.689, -154.632
3190.627, -99.969, -156.195
3248.089, -100.469, -158.041
3306.586, -100.644, -159.622
3366.137, -100.629, -161.068
3426.760, -101.562, -163.512
3488.475, -102.363, -165.870
3551.302, -102.167, -167.272
3615.260, -101.974, -168.714
3680.370, -102.055, -170.462
3746.652, -102.891, -172.993
3814.129, -103.815, -175.637
3882.820, -103.469, -177.031
3952.749, -103.874, -179.195
4023.937, -104.056, -181.152
4096.407, -104.680, -183.563
4170.182, -105.183, -185.865
4245.286, -105.044, -187.535
4321.743, -105.541, -189.849
4399.576, -105.822, -191.954
4478.812, -106.187, -194.148
4559.474, -105.990, -195.786
4641.589, -106.222, -197.856
4725.183, -106.961, -200.437
4810.282, -107.153, -202.474
4896.914, -107.402, -204.570
4985.106, -107.350, -206.368
5074.887, -107.841, -208.710
5166.284, -108.540, -211.261
5259.328, -108.177, -212.752
5354.047, -108.851, -215.281
5450.472, -108.463, -216.748
5548.634, -109.168, -219.310
5648.563, -109.327, -221.326
5750.292, -110.141, -223.997
5853.854, -110.367, -226.081
5959.280, -110.150, -227.723
6066.605, -111.069, -230.500
6175.863, -110.857, -232.147
6287.089, -111.135, -234.284
6400.318, -111.114, -236.122
6515.586, -111.620, -238.488
6632.930, -111.630, -240.357
6752.388, -111.945, -242.532
6873.996, -112.445, -244.892
6997.795, -112.978, -247.284
7123.824, -113.114, -249.280
7252.122, -113.040, -251.066
7382.731, -113.181, -253.067
7515.692, -113.406, -255.152
7651.048, -113.909, -257.515
7788.842, -114.505, -259.972
7929.117, -114.056, -261.383
8071.918, -114.336, -263.523
8217.291, -115.112, -266.159
8365.283, -115.076, -267.983
8515.939, -115.691, -270.458
8669.309, -115.120, -271.748
8825.441, -115.586, -274.074
8984.385, -115.800, -276.148
9146.192, -116.421, -278.629
9310.913, -116.636, -280.705
9478.600, -116.705, -282.634
9649.307, -117.236, -285.025
9823.089, -117.063, -286.713
10000.000, -117.204, -288.714
\end{filecontents*}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164991/pgfplots-how-to-fill-bounded-area-under-a-curve-using-addplot-and-fill?rq=1
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every plot/.append style={very thick}]
\begin{semilogxaxis}[width=14cm,height=10cm,
                    grid = both,
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.7},
                    ymin =  -130,
                    ymax = -70,
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={\emph{Offset Frequency (Hz)}},
                    ylabel={\emph{Noise}},
                    extra y ticks = {-70}]

\addplot+ [smooth,blue,name path=A] table[mark = none, x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {\datafile};
\addplot+[draw=none,name path=B, domain=500:1000, mark=none] {-130};
\addplot+[gray, fill opacity=0.4] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=500:1000}];
\path[name path=cut] (axis cs: 500,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
            (axis cs: 500,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) --
            (axis cs: 1000,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) --
            (axis cs: 1000,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});
\draw[red,very thick,
        intersection segments={
          of=A and cut,
          sequence={R1--L2--R0}
        }];
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Response.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, I don't know why I've been getting that odd straight line on the plot. But I've found a temporary solution. I'll fix my previous answer soon too.